# Can the product of a disconnected metric space and a connected metric space be connected?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces

Given two metric spaces $(X,d_X)$ and $(Y,d_Y)$, we define the product space to be $(X\times Y, d_{X\times Y})$, where $d_{X\times Y}\big((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)\big):=(d_X(x_1,x_2)^p+d_Y(y_1,y_2)^p)^\frac{1}{p}$ for generality (p possibly infinite). We know that if $X$ and $Y$ are connected, then the product is connected, but is the converse true? i.e. If the product is connected, must it be the case that both $X$ and $Y$ be connected? I am inclined to believe so, but the way the problem which I'm working on phrases itself seems to suggest that I may be mistaken.

My attempt at a sketch of proof:

Without loss of generality assume that $X$ is disconnected. Let $A_X$ and $B_X$ be open sets such that $A_X\cap B_X =\emptyset$ and $A_X\sqcup B_X = X$. Let $A:=\{(x,y)|x\in A_X\}$ and $B:=\{(x,y)|x\in B_X\}$ lie in $X\times Y$ such that $A_X$ and $B_X$are their respective projections onto $X$. To prove that $X\times Y$ is disconnected, it remains to show that $A$ and $B$ are open in $X\times Y$. By a natural abuse of notation consider the (pseudo)metric $d_X$ on $X\times Y$ defined by $d_X\big((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)\big)=d_X(x_1,x_2)$. In the product space $X\times Y$, since $d_{X\times Y}\geq d_X$. the topology induced by $d_{X\times Y}$ is finer than $d_X$. Then since A and B are clearly open wrt $d_X$, they are open wrt $d_{X\times Y}$, and is thus a separation of the product space, thus demonstrating that it is disconnected.

Comment: If one of the factors is $\varnothing$, the product is $\varnothing$, hence connected, whatever the other factor is.

Comment: Whether $\varnothing$ is connected depends on which definition of connectedness one uses. In my opinion, the best definition is that, whenever the space is expressed as the topological disjoint union of subspaces, then one of those subspaces is the whole space. With this definition, $\varnothing$ isn't connected (because of the decomposition into no pieces).

Comment: Your proof is ok......The projections $p_X$ and $ p_Y$, of $X\times Y$ to,  respectively, $X$ and $Y$ are continuous. So  $A=p_x^{-1}A_X$ and $B=p_Y^{-1}B_Y$ are open..... Small point: We must assume $Y$ is not empty.

Answer (score 2):

There is a useful general theorem you can apply (and I'll stick to the case of nonempty topological spaces to avoid pathologies): if $f : C \to D$ is a continuous surjective map from a nonempty, connected topological space $C$ to a topological space $D$, then $D$ is connected. The proof is simple: if $D$ is disconnected then $D=U \cup V$ where $U,V$ are open, nonempty and disjoint; so $C=f^{-1}(U) \cup f^{-1}(V)$ where $f^{-1}(U)$,$f^{-1}(V)$ are open, nonempty, and disjoint; so $C$ is disconnected.

Applying this using the two projection functions $X \times Y \mapsto X$ and $X \times Y \mapsto Y$, each of which is surjective and continuous, it follows that if $X \times Y$ is connected then $X$ and $Y$ are both connected.

Comment: +1.  No need to explicitly assume $D$ is nonempty, by the way -- the codomain of a function from a nonempty set must be.

Answer (score 1):

> Naturally, let $A$ and $B$ lie in $X\times Y$ such that $A_X$ and $B_X$are their respective projections onto $X$.

The word naturally doesn't seem to mean anything here, and this doesn't uniquely identify what $A$ and $B$ are.   What you want to do is define $A := A_X \times Y$ and $B := B_X \times Y$.

> By a natural abuse of notation consider the metric $d_X$ on $X\times Y$ defined by $d_X\big((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2)\big)=d_X(x_1,x_2)$.

That's not a metric.  The distance between $(x, y_1)$ and $(x, y_2)$ is zero.

Comment: Pardon me for being sloppy, I meant to define $A$ and $B$ in $X\times Y$ as $A:=\{(x,y)|x\in A_X\}$ and $B:=\{(x,y)|x\in B_X\}$. Subsequently, although $d_X$ may not be a metric on $X\times Y$, it does not seem to affect the argument that $A$ and $B$ are open, does it?

Comment: This should be roughly okay, except you need to take into account what @daniel-fischer pointed out in the comments.